# My Ubuntu does not boot, and the the error during that is "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY, RUN FSCK MANUALLY". If i run "fsck /dev/sda2" it works,but why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fsck

i had an error at Ubuntu 17.04 before booting. It said: "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY, RUN FSCK MANUALLY" . So i typed after finding the problem's solution in Google: fsck /dev/sda2 . After rebooting my System worked normally without any errors. My question is: what does fsck /dev/sda2 mean?

Comment: This isn’t a programming question so it will likely get closed, but it means your disk had a problem... you should back up your data and hope it was a one time thing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`fsck` is the linux file system check command. You can use it to check if there are any errors or attempt to repair errors in the file system. `man fsck` to learn more about that.

`dev/sda2` is the drive which is causing the error. The `a` part refers to the first disk, so most likely the one you're booting from and the `2` part means the second partition.

Without anymore details it's quite hard to tell what the actual problem is. Possibly it's a corrupted drive or that it is dying. If possible try to back up your data from it.